# In the Ideal Gas Law, why is the variable for Gas Constant labeled as an R?

Tags: ideal-gas, history, gas

The formula is written as *PV=nRT*.

Seems like they had a logical progression going on in regards to labeling for the most part:

**P**ressure being a **P**,

**V**olume being a **V**, and

**T**emperature being a **T**.

But the Gas Constant being labeled **R** makes no real sense. Maybe it was a random letter chosen, but I suspect the real answer might prove interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant)

> Some have suggested that it might be appropriate to name the symbol R
>   the Regnault constant in honour of the French chemist Henri Victor
>   Regnault, whose accurate experimental data were used to calculate the
>   early value of the constant; however, the exact reason for the
>   original representation of the constant by the letter R is elusive.

Comment: Ahh I actually read the Wikipedia page and missed that somehow! Thx for being polite about it. :)